# SQL :: How to find records with most common in search string (Tags field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have tbl_Articles:

```
id    title       tags
=================================
1     article1    science;
2     article2    art;
3     article3    sports;art;
```

I am looking for a query to return records from tbl_Articles which have **most common words** with a specific tags string (Ex: **politics;art;**):

*EX:* Select (something from tbl_articles) where Tags *has common in* "**politics;art;**"

*Result:*

tbl_Articles

```
id    title       tags
=================================
2     article2    art;
3     article3    sports;art;
```

Comment: You should consider building your tag system relationally. Using a join table between a tag table and an article table. This looks like it's built incorrectly to do the query you want to do in an efficient manner. Generally, with any database, you want to avoid doing partial string matches to find records, and if one row has attributes, and potentially many of them, they should be stored relationally rather than flattened.

Comment: Any answer addressed your query? or you need more help ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for this?

```
select a.*
from articles a
where ';'+tags+';' like '%;politics;%' and
      ';'+tags+';' like '%;art;%'
```

Notice that I use the separator at the beginning and end so you can have "art" and "smart" as tags.

Comment: +1 I actually cover this approach here http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings - it's the one case where inline `LIKE` out-performs CLR and all other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task using `LIKE predicate` **BUT**, Please note that it only works on `Character Patterns`.

I think you are looking for **[Full-Text Query](https://amitpatriwala.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/fulltext-search-in-sqlserver-2005/)**. The `Free Text` not only returns the exact wording, but also the nearest meanings attached to it.

For more details **[check](https://amitpatriwala.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/fulltext-search-in-sqlserver-2005/)** for the following types..

1. FREETEXT
2. FREETEXTTABLE
3. CONTAINS
4. CONTAINSTABLE

The Performance benefit of using `Full-Text` search can be best realized when querying against a large amount of unstructured text data. A `LIKE` query (for example, ‘%microsoft%’) against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a `Full-Text` query (for ‘microsoft’) can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.